# Differentiating a function and using the result to calculate the indefinite integral of another.

Tags: integration, derivatives

We should differentiate the function $f(x) = \sqrt{cosx}$ and use the result to calculate the indefinite integral $\int \frac{sinx}{\sqrt{cosx}}dx$.

So I started by differentiating $f(x) = \sqrt{cosx}$ and got the result $-\frac{sinx}{2\sqrt{cosx}}$, which is fine.

However.. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to see next. I know that $\int \frac{sinx}{\sqrt{cosx}}dx$ is very similar to $-\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{cosx}}$.

So I know that when we differentiated $\sqrt{cosx}$ we almost got the thing we want to integrate. But the difference is.. well.. $-\frac{1}{2}$, it seems.

Could anyone explain the next steps?

Comment: Please prefix functions like $\sin$ and $\cos$ with `\` like so: `\sin` and `\cos`. Also please consider using diplaymode for some of your equations, that is done by having 2 `$`s around the formula instead of one: `$\sin x$` and `$$\sin x$$` becomes $\sin x$ and $$\sin x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about calculating $\displaystyle -2\int -\frac12\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx$?

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx=-2\underbrace{\int -\frac12\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx}_{\sqrt{\cos x}}=-2\sqrt{\cos x}+C$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Am I correct that the reasoning is.. I see that the difference is $-\frac{1}{2} * $ what I have, and thus.. in order to add that (so I can calculate the integral), I will need to multiply the whole thing by -2 so I don't change anything?

Comment: @user2451412 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks, you're a legend.

Comment: No problem! As always, click the checkbox :)

Comment: I've asked questions here three times and you've answered I think.. most likely every one of them. And you always do it very well, like, you really know your math and can explain it well. So thanks a lot, you deserve a lot of praise.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Glad I could help!